# Clear label votes from other users in gerrit

Tags: label, gerrit, review, vote

In the code review GUI, the administrators can remove the votes from other users.

My question is, how to achieve this using command line or using the REST API? by using the command line, I can only add/change the vote to the same user.

[image]

Comment: it's possible to use REST API to submit a vote using on_behalf_of the original voter, but currently I'm still blocked by the calling of the API, because it always return a 400 code, saying "on_behalf_of is not a valid option"